# Unsure how to fix; a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am currently learning composition and am stuck on this issue

I am not sure how to fix the "nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object" error i keep getting

I'm not allowed to modify main() in any way

```
int main()
{
     Time t(23, 59, 58);
     Date d(12, 31, 2017, t);
 // ...
}
```

I get the error message "a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object" at Time = time (bolded "time" is where it is red underlined in visual c++)

I believe the error has something to do with the composition with Time time, but i am unsure

```
class Date
{
public:
    explicit Date( int = 1, int = 1, int = 1900, Time = **time**); 
    // ...
private:
    Time time;
    // ...
}
```

Date constructor

```
Date::Date( int mn, int dy, int yr, Time timeObject)
: time{ timeObject }
 // ...
```

time class

```
class Time
{
public:
    explicit Time( int = 0, int = 0, int = 0 );
    // ...
private:
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;
}
```

time constructor

```
Time::Time( int hour, int minute, int second )
{ //...
}
```

The other threads that I have read regarding this error seemed to be more complex compared to what i currently know

Any advice on how to fix this error would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Change the `Time = time` to `Time timeobject` or some other name. The compiler is interpreting the default value `time` to be the member variable `time`.